# PrepareHeaderForMatch change in CSVHelper v23

Tags: csvhelper

Breaking changes in CSVHelper v23 includes "All delegates now take in a single struct argument."  PrepareHeaderForMatch is one of those delegates.  I get a compile error "Delegate 'PrepareHeaderForMatch' does not take 2 arguments".

I'm sorry about the basic question, but I am not sure how to fix PrepareHeaderForMatch in my code.  I'm sure it's simple, but I cannot find any examples or help yet on the web.  Maybe this post will help someone else in the future.

```
        var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        { 
            HeaderValidated = null,
            MissingFieldFound = null,
            PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) => header.ToLower()   // Match header and property names after converting to lower case
        };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been scratching my head on this one as well. The release notes as you say give no indication how to fix the problem, and the documentation has not been updated. I finally had to view the [source code](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/ConfigurationFunctions.cs) to solve it.

This works:

```
var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
{ 
    PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToLowerInvariant()
};
```

I prefer the new class for the args, but a simple example on a breaking change would have been nice.

Comment: Thank you, that code change does compile successfully now.  I'm not sure what was changed or why (I'm certainly not a C# expert!), but it would help as you said for Josh or a volunteer to provide some examples to help understand how to re-code for breaking changes.

Comment: The change log stated this, but I forgot to update examples. I'll do that today.

Comment: There is a feature request for having a migration guide in the docs, so that will be there in the future.

Comment: @JoshClose Thanks! That's awesome. I am updating from v12 so I had plenty to worry about lol. Its a fantastic library btw.